# List view issue

Tags: java, android, listview

I created a list view with two labels and a image view.
I need to hide the image view in some rows . I dont know how to hide it.
I tried `mycell.imagecomponent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
 Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use View.GONE ; I recommend [This article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)